# How to add an extra row (containing a Button and corresponding event handler) to the GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

This must be something that a lot of people have done. Basically, it's a custom GridView (i.e. inherited control) with the ability to update all rows at once. I've tried putting the "update all" button in various places (footer, pager, outside the grid), but it looks neatest (to me) when the button is in an extra row as the last row of the GridView.

NB: The pager row is not a suitable place for this button because this custom control could be used in a situation where paging is false. Similarly, the normal footer may be required for some other purpose (e.g. totals).

Here's my code for putting the button in the correct place (with apologies for the terse variables etc.):

```cs
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);
        //Add an extra row to the table...
        if (_updateAllEnabled)
        {
          GridViewRow r = base.CreateRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.Footer, DataControlRowState.Normal);
          Button btn = new Button();
          TableCell c = new TableCell();
          btn.ID = "UpdateAllButton";    // tried with and without this line
          btn.Text = "Update All";
          btn.Click += new EventHandler(UpdateAll);
          r.Cells.Add(c);
          c.Controls.Add(btn);
          Table t = this.Controls[0] as Table;
          c.ColumnSpan = this.Columns.Count;
          t.Rows.Add(r);           
      }
    }
```

This gives the appearance that I want, but the click event (UpdateAll) does not fire.

I assume that the stuff is being added too late in the life cycle (PreRender), but where else can I do this to ensure that the row is at the end of the GridView? I also thought that there might be trouble identifying the button, so I tried setting the ID. In any case, the ID in the generated HTML looks OK (consistent with "working" buttons in the pager row.

Is there a way for me to achieve this or am I attempting the impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easy to add an extra row into the grid. But the difficulty in your requirement is that the GridView's `RowCollection` should not contain this row since that would be error-prone. It should also be the very last row even if paging is enabled. This is (afaik) not possible.

Hence i've chosen to extend the pager with this functionality.

I'll add this as separate answer since my other is already too detailed and describes two different ways(footer,pager) to add controls to a `GridView` without extending it.

This approach extends a `GridView` as in your own requirement and is similar to my other pager-approach. But it's cleaner and only adds the additional row to the `BottomPager`. It woks also for every setting(AllowPaging=false,Pager-Position: Top,Bottom,BottomTop):

```
[DefaultProperty("EnableUpdateAll")]
[ToolboxData("<{0}:UpdateGridView runat=server></{0}:UpdateGridView>")]
public class UpdateGridView : GridView
{
    [Bindable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [DefaultValue("true")]
    [Localizable(true)]
    public bool EnableUpdateAll
    {
        get
        {
            Object val = ViewState["EnableUpdateAll"];
            return ((val == null) ? true : (bool)val);
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["EnableUpdateAll"] = value;
        }
    }

    private bool OriginalAllowPaging
    {
        get
        {
            Object val = ViewState["OriginalAllowPaging"];
            return (bool)val;
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["OriginalAllowPaging"] = value;
        }
    }

    private PagerPosition OriginalPagerPosition
    {
        get
        {
            Object val = ViewState["OriginalPagerPosition"];
            return (PagerPosition)val;
        }

        set
        {
            ViewState["OriginalPagerPosition"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnInit(System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["OriginalPagerPosition"] == null)
            OriginalPagerPosition = base.PagerSettings.Position;
        if(OriginalPagerPosition != PagerPosition.Bottom)
            PagerSettings.Position=PagerPosition.TopAndBottom;
        if (ViewState["OriginalAllowPaging"] == null)
            OriginalAllowPaging = base.AllowPaging;
        base.AllowPaging = true;
    }

    protected override void OnRowCreated(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Row.RowType)
        {
            case DataControlRowType.Pager:
                //check if we are in BottomPager
                if (this.Rows.Count != 0 && this.EnableUpdateAll)
                {
                    Button btnUpdate = new Button();
                    btnUpdate.ID = "BtnUpdate";
                    btnUpdate.Text = "Update";
                    btnUpdate.Click += new EventHandler(UpdateAll);
                    var tblPager = (Table)e.Row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
                    var row = new TableRow();
                    var cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.ColumnSpan = tblPager.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
                    cell.Controls.Add(btnUpdate);
                    row.Cells.Add(cell);
                    tblPager.Rows.Add(row);
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        bool bottomPagerVisible = 
            OriginalAllowPaging && 
            PageCount > 1 && 
            (OriginalPagerPosition == PagerPosition.Bottom || OriginalPagerPosition == PagerPosition.TopAndBottom);
        BottomPagerRow.Visible = bottomPagerVisible || EnableUpdateAll;
        var tblBottomPager = (Table)BottomPagerRow.Cells[0].Controls[0];
        tblBottomPager.Rows[0].Visible = bottomPagerVisible;
    }

    private void UpdateAll(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Tim, I see this a compromise solution (a fairly good compromise). However, my goal was to get this button in its own row. If you are telling me that what I want is impossible and this is the closest I'll get, then fair enough. If you put words to that effect at the top of this answer then that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: @Fruitbat: added a few words as explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to create your footer-controls  is  [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated.aspx#Y630)  since that's early enough in the lifecycle and also ensures that their recreated on every postback:

**Footer approach**:

```
protected void Grid_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer) {
        Button btn = new Button();
        TableCell c = new TableCell();
        btn.ID = "UpdateAllButton";   
        btn.Text = "Update All";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(UpdateAll);
        var firstCell=e.Row.Cells[0];
        firstCell.ColumnSpan =e.Row.Cells.Count;
        firstCell.Controls.Add(btn);
        while(e.Row.Cells.Count > 1)e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(e.Row.Cells.Count-1);
    }
}
```

Of course you have to set `ShowFooter` to `true`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
     ShowFooter="true" 
     OnRowCreated="Grid_RowCreated" 
     runat="server"
</asp:GridView>
```

**Pager approach:**

In my opinion this is the purpose of the `FooterRow`. But if you really want to ensure that your Button is in the very last row of a `GridView`(even below Pager as commented), i would try my next approach.

Here I'm using the pager for your costom control(s) by adding another `TableRow` to the `PagerTable` which inherits from [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

```
protected void Grid_RowCreated(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
    switch(e.Row.RowType){
        case DataControlRowType.Pager:
            Button btnUpdate = new Button();
            btnUpdate.ID = "UpdateButton";   
            btnUpdate.Text = "Update";
            btnUpdate.Click += new EventHandler(UpdateAll);
            var tblPager = (Table)e.Row.Cells[ 0 ].Controls[ 0 ];
            var row = new TableRow();
            var cell = new TableCell();
            cell.ColumnSpan = tblPager.Rows[ 0 ].Cells.Count;
            cell.Controls.Add(btnUpdate);
            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            tblPager.Rows.Add(row);
            break;
    }
}
```

To ensure that the pager is visible even if only one page is shown(note that the real pager is invisible if `PageSize==1`):

```
protected void Grid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e){
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)gv.BottomPagerRow;
    if(gvr != null) {
        gvr.Visible = true;
        var tblPager = (Table)gvr.Cells[ 0 ].Controls[ 0 ];
        //hide real pager if unnecessary
        tblPager.Rows[ 0 ].Visible = GridView1.PageCount > 1;
    }
}
```

Of course now you have to set `AllowPaging=true`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" 
   AllowPaging="true" 
   PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" 
   OnRowCreated="Grid_RowCreated"  
   OnPreRender="Grid_PreRender"
   OnPageIndexChanging="Grid_PageChanging"
   runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

**Final approach**(working for a custom GridView and all [`PagerPositions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.pagerposition.aspx)):

```
public PagerPosition OriginalPagerPosition{
    get { return (PagerPosition)ViewState[ "OriginalPagerPosition" ]; }
    set { ViewState[ "OriginalPagerPosition" ] = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(!IsPostBack) OriginalPagerPosition = GridView1.PagerSettings.Position;
    GridView1.PagerSettings.Position = PagerPosition.TopAndBottom;
    GridView1.AllowPaging = true;

    // databinding stuff ...
}
```

Keep the `RowCreated` the same as above in *Pager approach*.

Visibility of top/bottom pagers will be controlled in `PreRender` according to the `OriginalPagerPosition` property. Both pagers are created even with `PagerPosition=TOP`, the bottom pager is required for your additional control(s):

```
protected void Grid_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    GridViewRow tpr = (GridViewRow)gv.TopPagerRow;
    GridViewRow bpr = (GridViewRow)gv.BottomPagerRow;
    tpr.Visible = gv.PageCount > 1 && (OriginalPagerPosition == PagerPosition.Top || OriginalPagerPosition == PagerPosition.TopAndBottom);
    bpr.Visible = true;
    var tblBottomPager = (Table)bpr.Cells[ 0 ].Controls[ 0 ];
    tblBottomPager.Rows[ 0 ].Visible = gv.PageCount > 1 && (OriginalPagerPosition == PagerPosition.Bottom || OriginalPagerPosition == PagerPosition.TopAndBottom);
    var tblTopPager = (Table)tpr.Cells[ 0 ].Controls[ 0 ];
    tblTopPager.Rows[1].Visible = false;
}
```

**Note**: if you are extending the GridView control, you have to replace all occurences of `GridView1`(my test-grid) with `this`.

Comment: Yeah. Been there, done that. In fact, to get it to look nice, you have to remove all "excess" cells first. `for (int i = e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i > 0; i--) {                 e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(i); }` I have this as my "will do for now solution". The problem is, what if I need to use the footer for some other purpose? Also the PagerRow comes after the footer and I want this button in the last row of the grid.

Comment: You may have the beginning of an idea there. More work needs to be done to cater for the case when a Pager is not required. I'll have a play around with this and see if it will work.

Comment: @Fruitbar: Note that the real pager is invisible if paging is not necessary. If it's a custom control inheriting from GridView, you could simply `AllowPaging=true` in init-event.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. I thought I could keep track of the original values of AllowPaging and PagerPosition so that the button wouldn't interfere with the intended pager settings. But it always ends up with AllowPaging=true (presumably reconstructed from ViewState). Testing this with 4 GridViews: 1) No Paging 2) Pager Top 3) Pager Bottom 4) Pager TopAndBottom.

Comment: @Fruitbat: You've lost me there. In what way is the button interfering? My pager approach works as expected with: _`No Paging`_ and _`Pager Bottom`_(default) even when paging is not necessary because `PageCount==1`. On _`Pager Top`_ and _`Pager TopAndBottom`_ the update button will be below the pager controls in the next `TableRow`. If this is not desired, what is your concrete requirement?

Comment: Yes, I may have lost myself. For some reason all GridViews on my test page were ending up Pager.Position.TopAndBottom. It turned out I had this set up in an App_Themes skin file. Bear with me, I'm still trying to get this to work.

Comment: @Fruitbat: Edited again my answer to provide an approach that should work for all `PagerPositions`.

Comment: I think I'll delete my interpretation of the Pager solution as I'm not sure that it adds anything. At this point I think that the Pager solution is too complicated and doesn't get close enough to what I'm looking for. I don't see how you avoid the update button in the top pager. At the moment, I prefer the footer solution (until I need to use footers for something else) or a button outside the grid.

Comment: @Fruitbat: Of course i'm adding the update-button in the top pager. But it won't get rendered to the client since it's invisible by default(`tblTopPager.Rows[1].Visible = false;`, the last line in PreRender). So it doesn't hurt at all but it allows to provide a property `UpdateAllPosition` easily similar to the PagerPosition.